# Missing assembly for Action<T>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

What is the assembly to use with `Action<T>`? I get an error on T not being accepted, that an assembly or namespace is missing.

```
Method(delegate { OnChange(); });


    private static void MethodUsingOtherMethod(Action<T> action)
    {
      //TODO
    }
```

If I put an extra `<T>` after `MethodUsingOtherMethod`  then T is accepted, but then the argument in the delegate above is not recognized.

I want to use `OnChange()` in the second method, to be called from there.

Comment: reference mscorlib and add `using System`. But every program references mscorlib.

Comment: How about writing your question a bit more coherently? And perhaps add a codesample that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I am using System; Am I overlooking something else? Should one use <T> before (Actoin<T> action) or not, do you know what that depends on?

Comment: This is the code that I have that is connected to the problem?

Comment: This question is really unclear. what do you mean by "an extra"? which error message do you get?

Comment: I assume it's a problem relating to the inference of some type parameter because you didn't give a delegate type at some point. But without the code I can't give you the details.

Comment: @kakka47 this is by far no complete code sample. Give some code you expect to compile but that doesn't.

Comment: the <  >  fell away, sorry about that!

Comment: @CodeInChaos technically it is possible to remove a reference to mscorlib in the advance setting of the project, but I don't see any reason for that.

Comment: Can you please rephrase? I don't think understand your question. If you put an extra what after MethodUsingOtherMethod? What error do you get? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I try to pass a method as a parameter to another method. It was supposed to be an extra < T >, but they fell away. I get the error that T is not recognized. I was wondering if I maybe was not declaring the right assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Action<T>` means that you need to pass a delegate accepting 1 argument of type T. So, if you want to pass OnChange, then you can just specify `Action` without the T.

That way, your code would look like this:

```
MethodUsingOtherMethod(OnChange);


private static void MethodUsingOtherMethod(Action action)
{
  //TODO
}
```

The error you got about T not being recognized is, because you didn't declare your method as a generic method (done by putting the `<T>` behind the method name). Because of that, the compiler didn't recognize T as a type argument and tried to look up a type called T, which doesn't exist.

You might want to look up Generics to understand what's going on there:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I thought that the method counted as a parameter, but I see it is just an action in itself. Will look into Generics!

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare your method as a generic method:

```
private static void MethodUsingOtherMethod<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
      //TODO
    }
```

Edit: By the way, you only need to do this if you need the passed in delegate to take a parameter of type T. If you need a parameterless method to be passed in, define your method like this:

```
private static void MethodUsingOtherMethod(Action action)
    {
      //TODO
    }
```

Comment: If I use the one topmost above I have to change my "OnChange();" to be of type T. Can a method be of type T? Cause I want to pass it to the delegate.

Comment: It appears from your code snippet that you don't need a parameter passed to the method, so use the 2nd method definition, which is the same as Botz3000's

Comment: Perfect, that is what I am going for!